# Usb can't be boot-able?

Tags: windows, usb, boot

Recently, I want to create a boot-able USB to re-install `windows 7`. And after creating boot-able USB with `Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool` and `windows7.iso`, I can't boot from my usb. However, If I try to create with my friend's USB, I can boot from it (tried it many times)! So can anyone explain what 's happen to my USB? How to solve it? One more problem, when I stick my USB to my laptop, there's always a file named `"usb label name".exe` in my usb (if I try to remove it or even format it, it will be automatically created later)? Can anyone give me a way to remove it? Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: have you checked out http://superuser.com/questions/278083/not-able-to-boot-from-usb?rq=1 or any of the other related ones?

Comment: One more, http://www.badzilla.co.uk/Bootable-Linux-USB-Memory-Stick-Problem-Solving

Comment: Check if any other OS is able to boot from the usb disk (for e.g linux)